# use Streams to generate a new list taking into account all the first list elements

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to map a list to another one. The decision is to be made on all the elements of the first list. Here is how it would look like, in crappy code :

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    MatchingClass myObject = new MatchingClass();
    System.out.println(myObject.getMatchingEnums(Arrays.asList("param1", "param3", "param2")));
    System.out.print(myObject.getMatchingEnums(Arrays.asList("param1", "param3", "param4")));

  }
}

enum TheEnums {
    elem1("param1", "param2"),
    elem2("param1", "param3");

  String[] parameters;
  TheEnums (String... parameters){
    this.parameters = parameters;
  }

  String[] getParams (){
    return parameters; 
  }

}

// you can add other public classes to this editor in any order
public class MatchingClass 
{
  public List<TheEnums> getMatchingEnums (List<String> givenParameters) {
    List<TheEnums> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TheEnums theEnum : TheEnums.values()){
      if (givenParameters.containsAll(Arrays.asList(theEnum.getParams()))){
            result.add (theEnum);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

This could be written better, but what I want to know is if we can use the Java 8 Stream to be able to do that.

Maybe using Collectors ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please rewrite your code to be correct Java? This is really annoying to read.

Comment: This doesnt even compile

Comment: Added a working compiled example

Comment: Since this `List<TheEnums>` never contains duplicates, an `EnumSet<TheEnums>` might be more appropriate. It could be created straight-forwardly without the Stream API: `EnumSet<TheEnums> result = EnumSet.allOf(TheEnums.class); result.removeIf(e -> !givenParameters.containsAll( Arrays.asList(e.getParams())));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
class MatchingClass {
    public List<TheEnums> getMatchingEnums(List<String> givenParameters) {

        List<TheEnums> enumsList = Arrays.asList(TheEnums.values());

        return enumsList.stream()
                .filter(e -> givenParameters.containsAll(Arrays.asList(e.getParams())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for `List<TheEnums> enumsList = Arrays.asList(…)` here. You can stream an array directly: `Arrays.stream(TheEnums.values()). …`. Or you use `EnumSet.allOf(TheEnums.class).stream(). …`